# Drop NaN cells and move non-null values according to Datetime index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have  a `DataFrame` given like this:

```
                     a     b      c       d
2014-02-10 23:30:00 25.1  NaN    NaN     NaN
2014-02-10 23:30:00 NaN   15.34  NaN     NaN
2014-02-10 23:30:00 NaN   NaN    123.54  NaN
2014-02-10 23:30:00 NaN   NaN    NaN     1.34
```

where for one time step I've got 4 values - one value per column. All other are `NaN`.

Is it possible to drop `NaN` values and leave only 4 values per one time step? To have something like this:

```
                     a     b      c       d
2014-02-10 23:30:00 25.1  15.34  123.54  1.34
```

I've tried applying solution from [Remove NaN 'Cells'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25942076/2669472)  given by @unutbu, but without any success:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import functools

def drop_and_roll(col, na_position='last', fillvalue=np.nan):
    result = np.full(len(col), fillvalue, dtype=col.dtype)
    mask = col.notnull()
    N = mask.sum()
    if na_position == 'last':
        result[:N] = col.loc[mask]
    elif na_position == 'first':
        result[-N:] = col.loc[mask]
    else:
        raise ValueError('na_position {!r} unrecognized'.format(na_position))
    return result

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}')

print(df.apply(functools.partial(drop_and_roll, fillvalue='')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) the index and call [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum):

```
In [70]:
df.groupby(df.index).sum()

Out[70]:
                        a      b       c     d
2014-02-10 23:30:00  25.1  15.34  123.54  1.34
```

Comment: I've received an error `AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

Comment: Can you post data and code to reproduce this error as I can only see your limited data set

Comment: I've restarted the kernel and now everything works. **Brilliant** solution !

Comment: You may have had some stale state, glad I could help