# how to delete nan in df from row without losing the whole row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

G'day, how can I drop the nan values without losing the whole row?
This is how my `df` looks like.

[image]

I have tried the `pandasdf = schule.dropna()`  But this deleted everything in the rows.

But I have to keep the values, because at the end, I want them to go upwards.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to replace them by None? Because it is not clear what you want to achieve, there will always be a value (NaN, None or useful values)

Comment: can you show us sample output which you want?

Comment: What values you want to replace in place of nan? @Noel

Comment: My guess is that they don't want to replace `NaN`, but instead combine all rows in the df into a single row, replacing `NaN` with the value obtained from a different row.

Comment: I want them to coalesce.

Comment: yes, @WesleyBowman isn't that replacing?

Comment: This looks as if fixing the parser that created the dataframe would make more sense...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941979/remove-nan-cells-without-dropping-the-entire-row-pandas-python3

Comment: @KarthickMohanraj thank you, this is very helpful! I will try this. If it won't work for me, I will slice the columns and do regular cleaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it might help. you can try it  !!!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per your problem statement, you want to give less priority to nan values and bring the non-nan values to the top.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import functools

def drop_and_roll(col, na_position='last', fillvalue=np.nan):
    result = np.full(len(col), fillvalue, dtype=col.dtype)
    mask = col.notnull()
    N = mask.sum()
    if na_position == 'last':
        result[:N] = col.loc[mask]
    elif na_position == 'first':
        result[-N:] = col.loc[mask]
    else:
        raise ValueError('na_position {!r} unrecognized'.format(na_position))
    return result

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}')

print(df.apply(functools.partial(drop_and_roll, fillvalue='')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting to backfill values and then drop any duplicates that appear in any of the columns this example works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['POINT_1.1', 'POINT_1.2', pd.NA],
    [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'POINT_1.3'],
    ['POINT_2.1', 'POINT_2.2', pd.NA],
    [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'POINT_2.3']

]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

#            0          1          2
# 0  POINT_1.1  POINT_1.2       <NA>
# 1       <NA>       <NA>  POINT_1.3
# 2  POINT_2.1  POINT_2.2       <NA>
# 3       <NA>       <NA>  POINT_2.3

t = df.T.bfill().T.bfill()
t

#            0          1          2
# 0  POINT_1.1  POINT_1.2  POINT_1.3
# 2  POINT_2.1  POINT_2.2  POINT_2.3

for column in t.columns:
    t = t.drop_duplicates(column)
t

#            0          1          2
# 0  POINT_1.1  POINT_1.2  POINT_1.3
# 2  POINT_2.1  POINT_2.2  POINT_2.3
```