# Remove empty cells and move content to the left Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file which contains the following structure with no header or index - I've added just the column header from Excel without existing in my table:

| A | B | C | D | E | ... | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XLS | 1231341231 | 123123asdad1923 | NaN | NaN | ... | 123123asdad1923 |
| DEF | XLS | 1231231231 | 1231823asda9123 | NaN | askda213 | ... | 123123asdad1923 |
| XYZ | XLS | 1231231233 | 2138820394832sd | NaN | NaN | ... | asdasdq2ew12332 |

I would need that all the cells that contains `NaN` to be removed and while NaN, move the cells to the left.

Output should look like:

| A | B | C | D | E | ... | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XLS | 1231341231 | 123123asdad1923 | 123123asdad1923 |  |  |  |
| DEF | XLS | 1231231231 | 1231823asda9123 | askda213 | ... | 123123asdad1923 |  |
| XYZ | XLS | 1231231233 | 2138820394832sd | asdasdq2ew12332 |  |  |  |

I have found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941979/remove-nan-cells-without-dropping-the-entire-row-pandas-python3) dropped on Stackoverflow, but the answer is not doing any change:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
df = df.fillna('')

df.to_excel("test_modified.xlsx", index=False, header=False)
```

Any ideas how can achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Will there ever be multiple sequences of NaNs in a row? e.g. `a b NaN NaN c d NaN NaN`?

Comment: What does "not working" mean in your case? No change from input to output? An error? Something else?

Comment: @richardec: Thank you for your reply. It's completely dynamically - we can have `a NaN b NaN` or we can even have `a b c NaN NaN NaN`.

Comment: @BigBen: Thank you for your reply. It is not changing anything.

Comment: In the case of `a NaN b NaN` - should the output become `a b NaN NaN`?

Comment: @richardec: Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I thought of would be to for each row, sort the row with a custom sorting function that returned 0 for NaN and 1 for non-NaN, effectively moving (but without changing the order of) all non-NaN values to be consecutive, and leaving the NaNs at the end:

```
new_df = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(sorted(row.tolist(), key=lambda x: np.isnan(x) if isinstance(x, float) else 0), index=row.index), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
     A    B           C                D                E                J   K
0  ABC  XLS  1231341231  123123asdad1923  123123asdad1923              NaN NaN
1  DEF  XLS  1231231231  1231823asda9123         askda213  123123asdad1923 NaN
2  XYZ  XLS  1231231233  2138820394832sd  asdasdq2ew12332              NaN NaN
```

Comment: @richarddec: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then I propose to transpose the dataset, process it, and transpose it back.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"],
        "B": ["XLS", "XLS", "XLS"],
        "C": ["1231341231", "1231231231", "1231231233"],
        "D": ["123123asdad1923", "1231823asda9123", "2138820394832sd"],
        "E": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        "F": [np.nan, "askda213", np.nan],
        "I": ["blabla", "blabla", np.nan],
        "K": ["123123asdad1923", "123123asdad1923", "asdasdq2ew12332"],
    }
)

print(df)
# transpose
df_transposed = df.T
# move NaN at end of column
df_transposed = df_transposed.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
# replace Nan by empty strings
df_transposed.replace(np.nan, "", inplace=True)
# transpose back
df = df_transposed.T
print()
print(df)
```

will output:

```
     A    B           C                D   E         F       I                K
0  ABC  XLS  1231341231  123123asdad1923 NaN       NaN  blabla  123123asdad1923
1  DEF  XLS  1231231231  1231823asda9123 NaN  askda213  blabla  123123asdad1923
2  XYZ  XLS  1231231233  2138820394832sd NaN       NaN     NaN  asdasdq2ew12332

     0    1           2                3                4                5                6
0  ABC  XLS  1231341231  123123asdad1923           blabla  123123asdad1923                 
1  DEF  XLS  1231231231  1231823asda9123         askda213           blabla  123123asdad1923
2  XYZ  XLS  1231231233  2138820394832sd  asdasdq2ew12332
```

Comment: @Thomas Ulrich: Thank you for your reply. Your code is removing the column Word2 completely which is not what I intend. Your example is not quite as the sample I proposed.